# How to understand this definition sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning, dictionaries

> arrogance:​the behaviour of a person when they feel that they are more important than other people, so that they are rude to them or do not consider them

[Oxford learner's dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/arrogance?q=arrogance)

I think the meaning of the explanation is clear, but I don't understand the grammatical function of "so that.....them". Is it within when-clause？

Comment: It sounds like you are asking the meaning of the "so that ... them" expression, which is not directly related to the definition of "arrogance" or any other word.

Comment: So you are saying the definition is not so perfectly constructed, doesn't stand congruity？

Comment: No @Robbyzhu, Andrew has summarised your question, but he has not offered any response to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**so that** introduces a clause that is a direct consequence of the preceding clause. here is the same concept described in a different sentence structure.

Person X feels that they are more important than other people. Because they think that they are more important than other people, they think that it is OK to be rude to them or not consider them. The behaviour of person X is arrogance.

Comment: So "so that...." Is an adverbial clause of result. I feel it a little awkward that **an Adverbial clause inside a when-clause**. It is not clear the writer wants to describe a behavior when someone **feel sth** or a behaviour when **being rude**

Comment: Maybe this way is better: Arrogance is:  rudeness or inconsiderateness displayed by people who believe they are more important than other people.

Comment: @Robbyzhu The original version indicates causality (the "of result" part of "adverbial clause of result"), but yours does not. Try this: "Arrogance is rudeness or lack of consideration displayed by people **because they** believe they are more important than other people. Anyway, I don't see anything wrong with nesting a **so that** clause inside a **when** clause. This nesting happens often.